# send facebook messages with spring social facebook

Tags: java, spring

i would like send a facebook messenger message with a java application through spring social facebook or other.
I made several attempts, no succeeded
please what is the script  to send a message with spring social facebook.

Comment: Can you please add some more details? please show what have you tried yet?

Comment: i need a code in java to send a facebook message with spring social facebook